# How to pass parameters in SOAP web service having a Method?

Tags: ios, objective-c, soap

I have never used SOAP based services and I am unsure of using the follwing SOAP Service.

http://workforce.wifisocial.in/WebServicesMethods/EmployeesWebService.asmx?op=EmployeesLoginMethod

In this service I need to pass 4 values with the parameters:
username, password, ipaddress and devicename.
And the output is in JSON format.

Kindly help to achieve the desired result.

Comment: Check [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35980742/how-to-create-dynamic-soap-envelop-in-objective-c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35980742/how-to-create-dynamic-soap-envelop-in-objective-c) and [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36982981/soap-request-using-nsurlsession-objective-c-or-swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36982981/soap-request-using-nsurlsession-objective-c-or-swift) it will help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is just a HTTP post request and pass the right XML data and set the HTTP headers:

```js
func soapRequest(username:String, password:String, ipAddress:String, deviceName:String){
        if let url = NSURL.init(string: "http://workforce.wifisocial.in/WebServicesMethods/EmployeesWebService.asmx"){
            let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
            let requestBody = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"><soap:Body><EmployeesLoginMethod xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\"><username>\(username)</username><password>\(password)</password><IpAddress>\(ipAddress)</IpAddress><deviceName>\(deviceName)</deviceName></EmployeesLoginMethod></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>"
            request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
            request.HTTPBody = requestBody.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            request.setValue("text/xml", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
            request.setValue("\"http://tempuri.org/EmployeesLoginMethod\"", forHTTPHeaderField: "SOAPAction")
            NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
                guard error == nil && data != nil else{
                    //handle error
                    return
                }
                if let responseString = String.init(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding){
                    print("\(responseString)")
                }
                //..........
                //Parse your XML response data
                //.........
            }).resume()
            
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: But In android they r getting reponse in Json Format where I am getting in Xml format.

Comment: Base on the API link you provide, the response will be in XML format. Although there might be a JSON api available somewhere.

Comment: where ineed to change that api

Comment: can u please help me out.

Comment: @DineshGurrapu The person supply you the API may have a Json version. Or you can do a search on converting XML to json, there is library can help u do that.

Answer (score 1):

May this will help you

Here is the way to call SOAP in Objective-C :

```
NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://yourbaseURLxxxxxxxx"];

    NSString *sSOAPMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n"
                              "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n"
                              "<soap:Body>\n"
                              "<EmployeesLoginMethod xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">"
                              "<username>iamiosguy@gmail.com</username>"
                              "<password>lovetocode</password>"
                              "<ipaddress>192.16.0.0</ipaddress>"
                              "<devicename>iPhone7</devicename>"
                              "</EmployeesLoginMethod>"
                              "</soap:Body>\n"
                              "</soap:Envelope>\n"];

    NSLog(@"-----Developed Envelope----%@",sSOAPMessage);



    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:baseURL];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setHTTPBody:[sSOAPMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [request addValue:@"http://tempuri.org/IService/EmployeesLoginMethod" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
    [request addValue:@"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"Data string = %@",string);

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"%s: AFHTTPRequestOperation error: %@", __FUNCTION__, error);
    }];

    [operation start];
```

Answer (score 0):

The output will be soap too from what I can see in the service definition.

I am assuming you want to call the function from another server using c# as of time of writing there is no indication on the used technology. You need to add wcf reference and call the method using the generated class.

> To add a reference to a service in the current solution
>   In Solution Explorer, right-click the name of the project that you want to add the service to, and then click Add Service Reference.
>   The Add Service Reference dialog box appears.
>   Click Discover.
>   All services (both WCF Data Services and WCF services) in the current solution are added to the Services list.
>   In the Services list, expand the node for the service that you want to use and select an entity set.
>   In the Namespace box, enter the namespace that you want to use for the reference.
>   Click OK to add the reference to the project.
>   A service client (proxy) is generated, and metadata that describes the service is added to the app.config file.

[MSDN How to: Add, Update, or Remove a WCF Data Service Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668183.aspx)

---

If you are posting from javascript, here is a vanilla js example.

```js
var soap_post_body = ""+
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>' +
'<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"'+ 'xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">'+
'  <soap12:Body>'+
'    <EmployeesLoginMethod xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">'+
'      <username>string</username>'+
'      <password>string</password>'+
'      <IpAddress>string</IpAddress>'+
'      <deviceName>string</deviceName>'+
'    </EmployeesLoginMethod>'+
'  </soap12:Body>'+
'</soap12:Envelope>';

xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', 'http://workforce.wifisocial.in/WebServicesMethods/EmployeesWebService.asmx');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8');
xhr.onload = function() {
    if (xhr.status === 200) {
        console.log(xhr.responseText);
    }
    else {
        console.log(xhr.status);
    }
};
xhr.send(encodeURI(soap_post_body));
```

Comment: <NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x176bb930> { URL: http://workforce.wifisocial.in/WebServicesMethods/EmployeesWebService.asmx } { status code: 500, headers {
    "Cache-Control" = private;
    "Content-Length" = 509;
    "Content-Type" = "application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8";
    Date = "Fri, 02 Sep 2016 05:17:34 GMT";
    Server = "Microsoft-IIS/8.0";
    "X-AspNet-Version" = "4.0.30319";
    "X-Powered-By" = "ASP.NET";
    "X-Powered-By-Plesk" = PleskWin;
} }

Comment: response getting like this